# q = name contains ' ' Google Drive Query to locate SPACES

Tags: google-apps-script, google-drive-api, drive

I have this google drive query for the Drive REST API 3.
q = name contains ' '

It returns a lot of files with and without spaces ( which mean its wrong from my point of view)
any suggestions for a way to make it work?

Comment: Are you sure you're using v3 of API? Post your working code here

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the following query:

```
q = name contains '\\s'
```

I tested it like this in the API explorer from the [files.list](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list) method of the Drive API V3 and it works perfectly.

[image]